# Custom Dialog or dialog themed activity

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog, themes, listener

I see many developers choosing to theme their activity as a dialog instead of using the android dialog and customize it.

I searched on the internet for this answer but couldn't find it.

Could someone give me the pro's and con's of the activity theme method? Of course, it gives you more freedom but are there any styling reasons to avoid customizing the standard dialog?

I, myself needed to re-use fragments in dialogs so I created a themed activity to comfort my needs but now I'm running into trouble at retrieving results from the themed activity.

Thanks in advance.
Bram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Start your activity using startActivityForResult.
2) Before you close your dialog-styled activity add needed data to intent extras and save it using SetResult(int, intent).
3) To process results add code to anActivityResult of parent activity that will retrieve data from saved intent.

no probs.

Yes, if you need to add heavy custom logic to your "dialog", then usage of styled activity is preferable.
In case of simple alerts - use Dialog.

Comment: First of all, thanks for your response. I know about the startActivityForResult method. However, I also have GridViews in my dialogs. When I click a button in my grid I need to send the button's information to the parent activity. I could even have to send a list of objects. Isn't this to much data to be passed between activities?

Comment: why do you need this? Are you closing dialog after button pressed? If no - maybe better to move code to child activity?

Comment: Yes I do, but I fixed my problem by letting a class listen to events in the fragment (the fragment is within my dialog activity). The listening class will get an event when a button has been clicked, and will also get the reference to the clicked button. After the event has been received it calls the fragment to close the dialog (getActivity.finish()). So the structure will be: activity (that gives the opening call) > listening class > dialog activity > fragment. Thanks for your help though. I'll accept your answer for helping me get back on track.

Answer (score 1):

A custom dialog is easier to create (you don't have to handle onCreate, onPause, screen rotations, ...), and have less overhead.

So you should use a custom dialog whenever you don't want to display something more complex than a dialog.